# Determining running time of an algorithm to compare two arrays

Tags: algorithm, runtime

I want to know how it is possible to determine the run time of an algorithm written in pseudocode so that I can familiarize myself with run time. So for example, how do you know what the run time of an algorithm that will compare 2 arrays to determine if they are not the same?

Array 1 = [1, 5, 3, 2, 10, 12]    Array 2 = [3, 2, 1, 5, 10, 12]
So these two arrays are not the same since they are ordered differently.

My pseudocode is:

1) set current pointer to first number in first array
2) set second pointer to first number in second array
3) while ( current pointer != " ") compare with same position element in other array
4) if (current pointer == second pointer)
    move current pointer to next number
        move second pointer to next number

5) else (output that arrays are not the same)
end loop

So I am assuming first off my code is correct. I know step 4 executes only once since it only takes 1 match to display arrays are not the same. So step 4 takes only constant time (1). I know step 1 and 2 only execute once also.

so far I know run time is 3 + ? (? being the run time of loop itself)

Now I am lost on the loop part. Does the loop run n times (n being number of numbers in the array?), since worst case might be every single number gets matched? Am I thinking of run time in the right way?

If someone can help with this, I'll appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: i edited the question -- you had 2 step 2s, but im too tired/altered to figure the other stuff out -- make sure this is still correct

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking about is called the **time-complexity** of your algorithm. We talk about the time complexity of algorithms using so called **Big-O** notation.

Big-O notation is a method for talking about the approximate number of steps our algorithms take *relative to the size of the algorithms input*, in the worst possible case for an input of that size.

Your algorithm runs in `O(n)` time (pronounced "big-oh of n" or "order n" or sometimes we just say "linear time").

You already know that steps 1,2, and 4 all run in a constant number of steps relative to the size of the array. We say that those steps run in `O(1)` time ("constant time").

So let's consider step 3:

If there are n elements in the array, then step 3 needs to do n comparisons *in the worst case*. So we say that step 3 takes `O(n)` time.

Since the algorithm takes `O(n)` time on step 3, and all other steps are faster, we say that the total time complexity of your algorithm is `O(n)`.

When we write `O(f)`, where `f` is some function, we mean that the algorithm runs within some constant factor of `f` for large values.

Take your algorithm for example. For large values of n (say n = 1000), the algorithm doesn't take exactly n steps. Suppose that a comparison takes 5 instructions to complete in your algorithm, on your machine of choice. (It could be any constant number, I'm just choosing 5 for example.) And suppose that steps 1, 2, 4 all take some constant number of steps each, totalling 10 instructions for all three of those steps.

Then for n = 1000 your algorithm would take:

Steps 1 + 2 + 4 = 10 instructions. Step 3 = 5*1000 = 5000 instructions.

This is a total of 5010 instructions. This is about 5*n instructions, which is a constant factor of `n`, which is why we say it is `O(n)`.

For very large n, the 10 in `f = 5*n + 10` becomes more and more insignificant, as does the 5. For this reason, we simply reduce the function to `f is within a constant factor of n for large n` by saying `f is in O(n)`.

In this way it's easy to describe the idea that a quadratic function like `f1 = n^2 + 2` is always larger than any linear function like `f2 = 10000*n + 50000` when n is large enough, by simply writing f1 as `O(n)` and f2 as `O(n^2)`.

Comment: +1 for the nice description. Just like to add to your answer... @Eric. the "3" that you have there is typically ignored. That in Big-Oh we're only interested in the significant quantities. "3" in this insignificant.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar, sorry but which "3" are you referring to?

Comment: my comment (for more Eric really) is now irrelevant since you've added the whole explanation about the insignificant numbers. In Eric's question he had : "so far I know run time is 3 + ? (? being the run time of loop itself)". That's the "3" I was referring to.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar, ah that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The running time is O(n) where n is the number of elements in the arrays. Each time you add 1 element to the arrays, you would have to execute the loop 1 more time in the worst case.